# Displaying/Processing iPhone Camera Frames with OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: iphone, c, opengl-es, 3d

Eventually, I'm looking to create a shader that can convert the video to black and white for me (And then applying some other effects that I'm not sure if I should disclose), simply because doing this on the CPU get's me around 1 frame a second.

Anyway, for right now, I simply wish to display the video frames to the screen. I can draw triangles to the screen, so I know that my OpenGL view is working correctly, and I'm getting NSLogs from the

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput 
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer 
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
```

method. This method is where I'm attempting to do all the drawing. Unfortunately, I'm doing something wrong... and the camera frame isn't drawing.

Here's my simple vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;

varying vec2 textureCoordinate;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
    textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy;
}
```

(I know that it's being compiled, and is working again, because of the primitives I'm able to render.)

Here's my simplistic fragment shader:

```
varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;

uniform sampler2D videoFrame;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(videoFrame, textureCoordinate);

}
```

And.... here's where I'm *attempting* to put it all together, haha:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput 
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer 
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {   

    //NSLog(@"Frame...");
    CVImageBufferRef cameraFrame = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);  
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(cameraFrame, 0);
    int bufferHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cameraFrame);
    int bufferWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cameraFrame);

    //these er, have to be set
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    // This is necessary for non-power-of-two textures
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    //set the image for the currently bound texture 
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, bufferWidth, bufferHeight, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cameraFrame));

    static const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,
    };

    static const GLfloat textureVertices[] = {
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f,  1.0f,
        0.0f,  0.0f,
    };

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, videoFrameTexture);

    // Update uniform values
    glUniform1i(videoFrameUniform, 0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareVertices);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, textureVertices);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBuffer);
}
```

Doesn't work right.

Any help would be ***extremely*** appreciated, I'm out of ideas and at a loss here. Thanks in advance!

**Edit : Here's my code I use to set up the view, load OpenGL and start the capture session.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    NSLog(@"Yo.");

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer*)[super layer];
        [eaglLayer setOpaque: YES];
        [eaglLayer setFrame: [self bounds]];
        [eaglLayer setContentsScale: 2.0];
        glContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI: kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
        if(!glContext || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext: glContext])   {
            [self release];
            return nil;
        }

        //endable 2D textures
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        //generates the frame and render buffers at the pointer locations of the frameBuffer and renderBuffer variables
        glGenFramebuffers(1,  &frameBuffer);
        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &renderBuffer);

        //binds the frame and render buffers, they can now be modified or consumed by later openGL calls
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBuffer);

        //generate storeage for the renderbuffer (Wouldn't be used for offscreen rendering, glRenderbufferStorage() instead)
        [glContext renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable: eaglLayer];

        //attaches the renderbuffer to the framebuffer
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBuffer);

        //sets up the coordinate system
        glViewport(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);          

        //|||||||||||||||--Remove this stuff later--||||||||||||||//

        //create the vertex and fragement shaders
        GLint vertexShader, fragmentShader;
        vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        //get their source paths, and the source, store in a char array
        NSString *vertexShaderPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"testShader" ofType: @"vsh"];
        NSString *fragmentShaderPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"testShader" ofType: @"fsh"];       
        const GLchar *vertexSource = (GLchar *)[[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: vertexShaderPath encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: nil] UTF8String];
        const GLchar *fragmentSource = (GLchar *)[[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: fragmentShaderPath encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: nil] UTF8String];

        NSLog(@"\n--- Vertex Source ---\n%s\n--- Fragment Source ---\n%s", vertexSource, fragmentSource);

        //associate the source strings with each shader
        glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);       
        glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);

        //compile the vertex shader, check for errors
        glCompileShader(vertexShader);
        GLint compiled;
        glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);
        if(!compiled)   {
            GLint infoLen = 0;
            glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLen);
            GLchar *infoLog = (GLchar *)malloc(sizeof(GLchar) * infoLen);
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, infoLen, NULL, infoLog);
            NSLog(@"\n--- Vertex Shader Error ---\n%s", infoLog);
            free(infoLog);
        }   

        //compile the fragment shader, check for errors
        glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
        glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);
        if(!compiled)   {
            GLint infoLen = 0;
            glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLen);
            GLchar *infoLog = (GLchar *)malloc(sizeof(GLchar) * infoLen);
            glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, infoLen, NULL, infoLog);
            NSLog(@"\n--- Fragment Shader Error ---\n%s", infoLog);
            free(infoLog);
        }   

        //create a program and attach both shaders
        testProgram = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(testProgram, vertexShader);
        glAttachShader(testProgram, fragmentShader);

        //bind some attribute locations...
        glBindAttribLocation(testProgram, 0, "position");
        glBindAttribLocation(testProgram, 1, "inputTextureCoordinate");

        //link and use the program, make sure it worked :P
        glLinkProgram(testProgram);
        glUseProgram(testProgram);

        GLint linked;
        glGetProgramiv(testProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linked);
        if(!linked) {
            GLint infoLen = 0;
            glGetProgramiv(testProgram, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLen);
            GLchar *infoLog = (GLchar *)malloc(sizeof(GLchar) * infoLen);
            glGetProgramInfoLog(testProgram, infoLen, NULL, infoLog);
            NSLog(@"%s", infoLog);
            free(infoLog);
        }

        videoFrameUniform = glGetUniformLocation(testProgram, "videoFrame");

        #if(!TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)
        //holding an error
        NSError *error = nil;

        //create a new capture session, set the preset, create + add the video camera input
        AVCaptureSession *captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
        [captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480];
        AVCaptureDevice *videoCamera = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoCamera error:&error];
        [captureSession addInput:videoInput];

        //set up the data ouput object, tell it to discard late video frames for no lag
        AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *dataOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
        dataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = YES;

        //create a new dispatch queue for all the sample buffers to be called into.grapher
        dispatch_queue_t queue;
        queue = dispatch_queue_create("cameraQueue", NULL);
        [dataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];
        dispatch_release(queue);

        //set some settings on the video data output
        NSString *key = (NSString *)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey; 
        NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]; 
        NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:value forKey:key]; 
        [dataOutput setVideoSettings:videoSettings];

        //add the data output
        [captureSession addOutput:dataOutput];

        //start the capture session running
        [captureSession startRunning];

        #endif
        //|||||||||||||||--Remove this stuff later--||||||||||||||//

        //draw the view
        [self drawView];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)drawView {
    //set what color clear is, and then clear the buffer
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.589f, 0.12f, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); //HUH?

    [glContext presentRenderbuffer: GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[This sample application of mine](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/ColorTracking.zip) has three shaders that perform various levels of processing and display of camera frames to the screen.  I explain how this application works in my post [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2010/10/22/gpu-accelerated-video-processing-mac-and-ios), as well as in the OpenGL ES 2.0 session of my class [on iTunes U](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=407243028).

In fact, the shaders here looks to be direct copies of the ones I used for the direct display of video frames, so you're probably already using that application as a template.  I assume that my sample application runs just fine on your device?

If so, then there has to be some difference between the starting sample and your application.  You appear to have simplified my sample by pulling some of the code I had in the `-drawFrame` method into the end of your delegate method, which should work fine, so that's not the problem.  I'll assume that the rest of your OpenGL setup is identical to what I had in that sample, so the scene is configured properly.

Looking through my code and comparing it to what you've posted, all that I can see that is different is a missing `glUseProgram()` call in your code.  If you've properly compiled and linked the shader program in code away from what you've shown here, you just need to employ `glUseProgram()` somewhere before you update the uniform values.

Also, you're binding the renderbuffer, but you may need

```
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

after your last line there to make sure the contents get to the screen (where `context` is your EAGLContext instance).

Comment: Wow, I actually did see your project, and your website was actually what led me to using OpenGL for this purpose. Thanks for that :) It took a while to read through, since there's three shaders being used, and it's hard to tell what does what, but it was a great help. -- Anyway, let me try out what you've suggested real quick.

Comment: It doesn't work, however, my setup is not identical to yours. I'm using a custom setup that was derived from the _OpenGL ES 2.0 Shading Language_ book. I'm going to go back and double check if there's any steps that I'm not taking that you are.

Comment: I honestly can't find anything that's different. I've edited the question and added the code I'm using to set up the view, and load the shaders...

Comment: @Matt - Did you try adding the `-presentRenderbuffer:` method after your last line in the callback delegate method?  I know it's probably redundant, but you could try adding in a `glUseProgram(testProgram);` before you update the uniforms in that same method, and see if it makes a difference.  I assume you don't see any OpenGL errors at any point in the setup or drawing, and all you get is a black display?

Comment: Yup. I tried adding `[glContext presentRenderbuffer: GL_RENDERBUFFER];` and I even tried adding the `glUseProgram(testProgram)` line before I update the uniform. All I'm getting is a green screen because I cleared the buffer using `glClearBuffer` after setting the clear color to green. There are no errors... I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong here...

Comment: @Matt - One other thing that I see is that you're setting your viewport based on the point dimensions of the view that hosts the OpenGL content, but you've set the `contentsScale` to be 2.0 (you really shouldn't hardcode that value).  The OpenGL display area will then have double the pixels, so you'll want to set the viewport size to the pixel size of the view, not its point size.  That should only cause a shrunken display, though.

Comment: @Matt - Also, I'd highly recommend refactoring the code so that you don't have all the setup code in one place, because this was a little hard to read.  In particular, grab Jeff LaMarche's GLProgram class from his article here: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/11/opengl-es-20-for-ios-chapter-4.html , which encapsulates everything related to compiling and using shaders and removes a lot of the boilerplate code you have to write for this.

Comment: @Matt - Finally, try placing `glCheckFramebufferStatus()` after your framebuffer setup and `glGetError()` throughout your drawing code to check for any OpenGL errors that your current code might be missing.

Comment: @Brad There aren't any errors being shown by `glCheckFrabebufferStatus()` or `glGetError()`. This is simply intended to be a brief proof of concept, so I put all the code in one place for simplicity. -- Anyway, I'm going to back up a bit and see if I can get a UIImage drawn as a texture first. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Matt - Another approach would be to start with my sample, which does work, and just remove stuff until it either stops working or gets to the state you want.  Then you could use that as a base for the processing you want to do.  I know a few people that have done this for their own image filters (like black and white, among others).

Answer (score 1):

This is because OpenGl context are not shared among different threads. So add
the following function to your (void)captureOutput: function.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
               ^{                       
                   //your code for displaying
               });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a threading issue? The captureOutput delegate can get called in a different thread from initWithFrame. Certainly, if you want to update the display using UIKit you need to make sure that this happens in the main thread, e.g., in your captureOutput function you would do something like:

```
// trigger the processing of this frame on the main thread
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(processFrame) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

And then put the UI update code into the processFrame function. I know you're not using UIKit for your display, but you also cannot share an OpenGL context between threads so perhaps this still applies to your case. Just a thought anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Is your image buffer chunky or planar?  I'm just passing through and haven't read every last piece of Apple's documentation here, but I did read that this question determines what you'll find at the base address of the buffer.